# require.js 'Backbone' is undefined IE only

Tags: internet-explorer, backbone.js, undefined, require

Site works perfect in all browsers but IE: 
SCRIPT5009: 'Backbone' is undefined

here is main.js which has been a labor of many hours and seems to match ALL of the API requirements?

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
    //  "jquery" : "jquery-1.7.2.min",
        "jquery.json" : "jquery.json-2.3.min",
        "jquery.jtemplates" : "jquery-jtemplates",
        "jquery.nailthumb" : "jquery.nailthumb.1.1.min",
        "jquery.ui" : "jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min",
        "jquery.fileupload" : "jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload",
        "jquery.iframe-transport" : "jquery-fileupload/jquery.iframe-transport",
        "jquery.ui.widget" : "jquery-fileupload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget",
        "jquery.fancybox" : "jquery.fancybox",
        "handlebars" : "handlebars",
        "input" : "input",
        "validator" : "cars/modules/carsValidator",
        "backbone" : "backbone",
        "underscore": "underscore"

    },
    shim: {
        'jquery.jtemplates': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
            //exports: "jQuery.fn.setTemplate"
        //},
        'jquery.json': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: "JSON"
        },
        'jquery.nailthumb':{
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'jquery.iframe-transport':{
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
       'jquery.fancybox':{
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'input': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'underscore'],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },
        'underscore' :{
            exports: '_'
        }

    } 
});
requirejs(["jquery"], function($) {
    window.$ = $;
    if (typeof console == "undefined") {
        this.console = {log: function() {}};
    }
    //this will invoke the script for the page
    if (module){
        require([module], function(module){});
    }


});
```

and my define call:

```
define(["jquery", "backbone"], function ($, backbone) {
    return backbone.Model.extend({
        update: function (message) {
            return this.type(message.type).message(message.message);
        },

        type: function (type) {
            if (type) {
                this.set({type: type});
                return this;
            }
            return this.get("type");

        },

        message: function (message) {
            if (message) {
                this.set({message: message});
                return this;
            }
            return this.get("message");
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be great....
Thanks

Comment: I ran into something similar and couldn't figure it out, until I noticed that by using the IE mode switching to test on IE9 and IE8 etc, made the app break. By clearing cache and refreshing after each switch, it magically worked both on IE9 and IE8 modes. Since I'm not expecting end users to do this switching, I left it at that.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not quite the solution you expected, but i ran into the same error on IE10.
The thing was that in older ie versions (ie9,8,7,6) it worked fine, so i decided to use the official MS 'hack' - [X-UA-Compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Just add the following line to your html's `<head>` section:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

Hope it helps!